# pandas.drop() not dropping columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the [Allstate data from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/allstate-claims-severity/data).
I am looping through the categorical columns to create dummies but the `pd.drop()` is not dropping my columns. I have tried

```
for i in range(44):
    dummies1 = pd.get_dummies(combined[cols_cat[i+71]], prefix=cols_cat[i+72])
    combined = pd.concat([combined,dummies1], axis=1)
    combined = combined.drop(combined[cols_cat[i+71]], axis=1)
```

or

```
for i in range(44):
    dummies1 = pd.get_dummies(combined[cols_cat[i+71]], prefix=cols_cat[i+72])
    combined = pd.concat([combined,dummies1], axis=1)
    combined.drop(combined[cols_cat[i+71]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

but when I check `combined.head()`, the dummies are created alright but the original columns still stay. The drop function has always given me trouble and I feel like I have still failed to understand the `inplace` part of the drop function after much use/research.
Here, `cols_cat` is an array of the column names I created earlier.

```
cols_cat = train.iloc[:,1:117].columns
cols_cont = train.iloc[:,117:131].columns
```

I am working on creating a model dataframe for people to try on so that this is easier to answer. Until then does someone spot any fundamental mistake I am making?

Comment: I think in combined.drop() you need to specify the column name, here you are giving it the entire column.

Comment: Second @BhushanPant see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). 
Another way to drop columns is `del df[col]`.

Comment: Apologizes I missed that. But he is not struggling with this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
combined = combined.drop(cols_cat[i+71], axis=1)
```

OR

```
combined.drop(cols_cat[i+71], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

As per [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), `axis=1` drops labels from columns, while `axis=0` drops labels from index.

Comment: Yes! I knew and didn't know this. It gets so confusing when to use labels and when to use an array. Is there an intuitive explanation?